# Rails 4 simple validate on create action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am getting the following error on a link_to in my view:

*Showing /var/www/application_name/app/views/order_log_notes/_form.html.erb where line #15 raised:
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]*

It seem that the validation is be ignored. Everything works fine if the :status value is selected.

Model:

```
class OrderLogNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  validates_presence_of :status
end
```

Controller:

```
 def new
    @order_log_note = OrderLogNote.new
  end

  def create
    @order_log_note = OrderLogNote.new(order_log_note_params)
    OrderLogNote.where('order_id = ?' ,@order_log_note.orderno).update_all(:isactive => 0)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order_log_note.save
        format.html { redirect_to order_path(@order_log_note.order_id), notice: 'Order log note was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order_log_note }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order_log_note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

View:

```
<h3>
  <%= link_to order_path(:id => params[:order_id]) do%><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span><%end%>
</h3>
```

Comment: Assuming line 15 of _form.html.erb is that `link_to` in the `h3`, when `params[:order_id]` is nil (as it is), what is your link supposed to be?

Comment: Do we have access of `params` inside the view ?

Comment: Do you have a **show** method in your controller? As for **create**, path should be `orders_path`

Comment: yes you have access to params in the view, and the error is occurring before the show action is hit.

Comment: nothing in the error message indicates that the problem has anything to do with validations.

Comment: @sevenseacat Ok. I was not aware of that.

Comment: Can you post your `order_log_note_params` method?

Comment: Thank you as I mentioned this error only occurs when I leave the :status blank. If I enter a :status the record is created and the :id is passed to the view. The validate is not catching that fact that no :status was entered and taking me back to the form to show the validation errors as it should. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Could you post the full view so we can understand it in context? Also I think the link can be just `order_path(params[:order_id])`